# Can not view logs of ASP NET Core Container

Tags: docker, logging, asp.net-core

Hello i have the following problem:

I have a `ASP .NET Core` server that is docker-ized and runs in a container with `docker-compose`.I send requests to my server via `postman` and i get `500-internal server error`.

I have tried:

- `docker attach myserver` and  i get nothing in the console.
- `docker logs myserver` i will get only the initial log (the startup).
- `telnet hostname port` and it seems it works to connect but i do not know how to create the request.

How can i get my hands on the `console` of my `ASP .NET Core` server?

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    db:
      image: redis:4.0.5-alpine
      container_name: redis0

      networks: 
        - redis-net
      ports:
        - 6381:6379

    backend:
      image: server
      container_name: server0
      build: ./Server
      command: ["dotnet","Server.dll"]
      depends_on:
        - db
      ports:
        - 9400:9300
      networks:
        - redis-net

networks:
    redis-net:
```

**dockerfile** (for server)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish /app
EXPOSE 9300
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            string port="9300";
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            var url =$"http://0.0.0.0:{port.ToString()}/";//Address.Default.ToUrl();
            Debug.WriteLine(url);
            builder.UseKestrel().UseUrls(url);
            return builder;

        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Configure your .net core app to print logs to the console

  `E.g. Console.WriteLine("Some application log");`
- Rebuild & run the containers

  `docker-compose build`

  `docker-compose up`
- Get the `container-id` for the running `server` container using

  `docker ps`
- Run this in another command window to follow the logs

  `docker logs --follow <container-id>`
- Run this to get into the container's bash shell

  `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`